# Polytunnel, green house or Shade Structures

Tags: overwintering, greenhouse, shade, hardening-off

For 1-2 year old trees for zone 8, H4 in UK, what would be better for overwintering, hardening, summer heat?

Polytunnel, a green house or some kind of 50-80% shade cloth structure?

And would the answer becdifferent for

Japanese Larch, European Larch, Japanese Black pine, Junipers and Maples?